# Not getting proof in basic lemma in Royden chap. 4.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> **Lemma 1.**
> Let $\{ E_i \}_{i=1}^n$ be a finite disjoint collection of measurable subsets of a set of finite measure $E$.
> For $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $a_i$ be a real number.
> $$
>   \text{
>     If
>     $\varphi = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot \chi_{E_i}$
>     on $E$, then
>     $\int_E \varphi = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot m(E_i)$.
>   }
> $$

> **Proof.**
> The collection $\{ E_i \}_{i=1}^n$ is disjoint but the above may not be the canonical representation since the $a_i$’s may not be distinct.
> We must account for possible repetitions.
> Let $\{\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_m\}$ be the distinct values taken by $\varphi$.
> For $1 \leq j \leq m$, set $A_j = \{ x \in E \mid \varphi(x) = \lambda_j \}$.
> By definition of the integral in terms of canonical representations,
> $$
>     \int_E \varphi
>   = \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j \cdot m(A_j).
> $$
> For $1 \leq j \leq m$, let $I_j$ be the set of indices $i$ in $\{1, \dotsc, n\}$ for which $a_i = \lambda_j$.
> Then $\{1, \dotsc, n\} = \bigcup_{j=1}^m I_j$, and the union is disjoint.
> **Moreover, by finite additivity of measure,
> $$
>   \text{
>     $m(A_j) = \sum_{i \in I_j} m(E_i)$
>     for all $1 \leq j \leq m$.
>   }
> $$**
> Therefore
> \begin{align*}
>      \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot m(E_i)
>   &= \sum_{j=1}^m \left[ \sum_{i \in I_j} a_i \cdot m(E_i) \right]
>    = \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j \left[ \sum_{i \in I_j} m(E_i) \right] \\
>   &= \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j \cdot m(A_j)
>    = \int_E \varphi.
> \end{align*}

Question: I don't understand why do we have a sum in the equality after the bold statement?

See, if say $1, 2 \in I_j$, then $a_1=a_2=\lambda_j$. This means that $E_1=E_2$ (because they're pairwise disjoint). Why doesn't Royden simply write $m(A_j) = m(E_i)$ for any $i \in I_j$?

I'd like to know how we're writing $A_j$ as the disjoint union of $E_i$ for $i \in I_j$ to be able to use finite additivity of measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_1 = a_2$ does not imply that $E_1$ was equal to $E_2$. Basically, the point of the lemma and proof is that $\varphi$ was taking the same values on different sets, when we want to just regroup them into a single set to use the definition of the integral. However, the union of such sets is still disjoint:

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the constant function equal to 1, and let $E_1 := \mathbb{R}_+$, $E_2 := \mathbb{R}_-^*$. $\varphi$ takes the value $1$ on both $E_1$ and $E_2$ but $E_1$ and $E_2$ were disjoint. (Probably should have chosen different sets to account for the finite measure requirement but you get the point).

Hope that clears it up!

Comment: Makes sense.  I wasn't thinking clearly. Thank you!